# How to get the width and height of a Photo in Android?

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I want to get the width and height of a photo (Image) given the path of the photo. Is there a way to do that without loading the photo to the memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

Bitmap btemp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath,options);
```

after this use below code to get height and width:

```
     options.outHeight     for height
      options.outWidth    for width
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just use BitmapFactory for this in following way:

```
Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
```

After this fields outHeight and outWidth of options will contain bitmap size. You can use decodeStream or other function, based on way you access the file, just don't forget to provide BitmapFactory.Options.